# How example can be run in test?

Tags: testing, go

I'm trying to run example in test.
However after running, warning is shown.

`testing: warning: no tests to run`

This example code includes comment `// Output comment.`

```
func ExampleMethod1() {
    fmt.Printf("result: %x", Method1())
    // Output: xxxx
}
```

What is wrong? When running test, I executed like this.
`go test -v xxxx_test.go`

Thanks.

Harry

Comment: The example should run and report an error as written.  There's no need to specify the .go file: `go test`  will run the examples in the current directory.  Is the example in a _test.go file?

Comment: Yes, this example code is included in _test.go file.

Comment: The file or function isn't being included for some reason. Please make a complete standalone example so others can verify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this post, I found it.

My xxx_test.go file didn't include Testxxx func at all.
xxx_test.go fires need it at least one.
After adding Testxxx func besides Example, example code worked!

Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, that's a bug. it will be fixed in go1.8

Comment: exactly what i just said :D